# How to Access a service which is denied by Admin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am an admin user, created another user attaching a policy where he cannot access Billing, he Somehow created another user who can access Billing. Now how do I restrict him from doing this stuff and How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Prevent them from creating IAM Policies/Roles/Users/etc. This will prevent them from creating new users with higher privileges than intended.

Comment: That works, But in one of the working scenario, this person needs to create Other Policies, Roles, and Users to add his team.

Answer (score 0):

Use a permission boundary. This will allow you to create a role/user that can create other policies and provision other users/roles only if they apply your permission boundary(permission boundaries are just AWS IAM policies by another name). The permission boundary would then have the limitations that you need to have in place.

For example the policy you attach to the our bad-annoying-user could be

```
{
      "Sid": "CreateRoleIffPermInPlace",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:CreateRole",
        "iam:CreateUser"
          .......
      ],
      "Resource": *,
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "iam:PermissionsBoundary": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:policy/myBillingPermissionBoundary"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "DenyThisUserBilling",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "aws-portal:ViewBilling",
        "aws-portal:ViewUsage"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
```

The permission boundary (another standalone policy) denying billing could then be
**myBillingPermissionBoundary**

```
    {
      "Sid": "DenyAnyOtherCreatedUserBilling",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "aws-portal:ViewBilling",
        "aws-portal:ViewUsage"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
```

Now anytime bad-annoying-user creates a new role or user he has to attach the Permission Boundary **myBillingPermissionBoundary** and because myBillingPermissionBoundary denies billing the new user cannot have billing view.